# Where would the best place to create Python objects be

Tags: python-3.x

So I'm making an OOP based program in Python and I wanted to ask: Where would be the best place to create an object? Let's say I have this object from my program.

```
class Player(Item):
    def __init__(self,Name,Diff,Money,Experience):
        self.name = Name
        self.diff = Diff
        self.money = Money
        self.experience = Experience
```

But I also have a main class game. Should I create the player object inside of class game, or maybe outside of all the classes so it is global? I don't know where I should make it so I can access it whenever I need it.

Comment: Depends on the scope you want to give to this new class, also on how often and in how many different files you will be making use of it.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "whenever I need it", where would you need them? You could instantiate the `Player` objects in say, `players` property of the `Game` object. Really depends..

Answer (score 0):

You're talking about where to *define* a class; this is a style question. Let's see what the [Style Guide for Python Code (PEP 8)](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#blank-lines) has to say about this:

> Surround top-level function and class definitions with two blank lines.

Ok... That's not too helpful, because now I have to use my own knowledge to answer the question. Erm...

Well, I suppose it depends on what you're trying to say. If you've got this:

```
class Game:
    class Player:
        def __init__(self, name, difficulty, money=0, experience=0):
            self.name = name
            self.difficulty = difficulty
            self.money = money
            self.experience = experience
```

then that suggests that if you change the `Game` implementation you'll have to change the `Player` implementation, and you can't change the `Player` implementation without changing the `Game` implementation; i.e., they're tightly coupled. So the code might carry on like this:

```
        def attack(self, game, other):
            game.hurt(other, 1000 // self.difficulty)
            if other.hp == 0:
                self.money += other.money
                other.money = 0

    def hurt(self, enemy, damage):
        enemy.hp -= damage // enemy.difficulty
        if enemy.hp <= 0:
            enemy.hp = 0
            enemy.die(self)
            self.player.experience += enemy.difficulty
```

This is not a great way of programming; everything's tied together too much and it's a big tangled mess. What's responsible for what? Instead, I'd have something more like this:

```
class Game:
    def __init__(self):
        self._entities = set()

    def register(self, entity):
        if entity not in self._entities:
            self._entities.add(entity)

    def unregister(self, entity):
        if entity in self._entities:
            self._entities.remove(entity)

    def end(self):
        print("Game over")
        raise SystemExit(0)

class Entity:
    def __init__(self, *args, game, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.game = game
        game.register(self)

    def die(self):
        self.game.unregister(self)

class Fighter(Entity):
    def __init__(self, *args, difficulty, money=None, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if money is None:
            money = (difficulty ** 2 - difficulty) // 2 + 1
        self.difficulty = difficulty
        self.money = money

        self._hp = 1000

    def attack(self, other):
        money = other.hit(self, self.difficulty):
        self.money += money

    def hit(self, other, damage):
        self._hp -= damage
        if self._hp <= 0:
            money = self.money
            self.money = 0
            self.die()
            return money
        # Didn't kill me, so gets no money
        return 0

class Player(Fighter):
    def __init__(self, *args, difficulty, money=None, experience=0, **kwargs):
        if money is None:
            money = 1000 // difficulty  # You get less money the more skilled
                                        # you are.
        self.experience = experience
        super().__init__(*args, difficulty=difficulty, money=money, **kwargs)

    def die(self):
        self.game.end()

    def attack(self, other):
        # Every time you attack an enemy, you get XP
        self.experience += other.difficulty
        super().attack(other)
```

This is crude and poorly designed, but you get the general idea. Each thing is in charge of dealing with its own stuff. Really the world should be in charge of checking whether all of the players are dead, but as it doesn't store players separately I couldn't show that in the example.